# How can I plot variable count on the y axis using ggbarplot function in the ggpubr package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a data frame df with two-factor variables. I used `ggplot2` to make a barplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = factor(c("2", "1", "1", "5", "3", "2", "4", "1", "5", "3")),
                 group = factor(c("one", "two", "two", "two", "one", "two", "one", 
                 "one", "two", "two"))
                 )

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group))
```

I want to make the exact same barplot using the `ggbarplot` function from the `ggpubr` package, but arguments for both x and y are required.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggbarplot(df,
          x = "x", y = "", fill = "group", color = "group")
```

How can I get count of x on the y axis as I was able to do using ggplot2?

I imagine this is relatively simple but I just can't figure it out - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible without creating a column with the count. What you can do is use `count` from `dplyr` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = factor(c("2", "1", "1", "5", "3", "2", "4", "1", "5", "3")),
                 group = factor(c("one", "two", "two", "two", "one", "two", "one", 
                                  "one", "two", "two"))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group))
```

[image]

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(group, x) %>%
  ggbarplot(., 
          x = "x", 
          y = "n", 
          fill = "group", 
          color = "group",
          xlab = "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, it has the same result.

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant. One follow up question - do you know what argument I can use to remove the legend? It looks like this would typically be customized using ggpar() from the ggpubr package, but it doesn't seem to be working in this case...

Answer (score 0):

To remove legend:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  count(group, x) %>%
  ggbarplot(., 
          x = "x", 
          y = "n", 
          fill = "group", 
          color = "group",
          xlab = "count") +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```